# RadioListTile not showing as selected/active after tapping on it

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I looked at other questions around, however, none has the same circumstances.

I have the following code where I populate RadioListTiles dynamically with a for loop:

```dart
  List<RadioListTile> buildListOp() {
    List<RadioListTile> opList = [];

    for (var op in widget.opciones!) {
      RadioListTile newItem = RadioListTile(
        title: Text(
          op.opTexto,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
        ),
        value: op.opId,
        groupValue: currentVote,
        activeColor: const Color(0xFFf672a7),
        fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => const Color(0xFFf672a7)),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            currentVote = value;
            // print('Voto $value');
          });
        },
      );

      opList.add(newItem);
    }

    return opList;    
  }
```

The variable `currentVote` for `groupValue` is being updated correctly. I can even send the data to the API. However, the Radio never gets selected or shown as active.

I'm being exploring all possibilities and my last thought is that the List for RadioListTiles is getting reset on every tap, hence the state goes back its unselected state.

Please take a look at my code and let me know any ideas. Thanks!

```dart
import 'package:adkondo_app/models/encuestas.dart';
import 'package:adkondo_app/services/api_services.dart';
import 'package:adkondo_app/views/encuestas_list.dart';
import 'package:adkondo_app/views/login_one.dart';
import 'package:adkondo_app/views/sub/poll_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:adkondo_app/views/sub/sub.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class Votar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Details encuesta;
  final List<Opciones>? opciones;
  final String propiedad;

  const Votar({super.key, required this.encuesta, this.opciones, required this.propiedad});

  @override
  State<Votar> createState() => _VotarState();
}

class _VotarState extends State<Votar> {

  late AppLocalizations myLocale;
  late Widget dialogContent;
  String? currentVote;
  Future<dynamic>? _responsePoll;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    myLocale = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    dialogContent = buildContent();
    super.didChangeDependencies();    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: whichPage(),
    );  
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    return (await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => closeDialog(context)
    )) ??
    false;
  }

  FutureBuilder<bool> whichPage() {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: ApiServices().tokenValid(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          bool tokenValido = snapshot.data!;
          if(tokenValido) {
            return WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: _onWillPop,
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: PollAppBar(barTitle: myLocale.polls, propiedad: widget.propiedad),
                drawer: const MyNav(),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                body: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 3,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    color: const Color(0xFF675aa9),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,            
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              widget.encuesta.pollConsulta, 
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center
                            ),
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 0),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            child: dialogContent,
                          ), 
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              )
            );
          } else {
            return LoginPageOne(reloadMsg: myLocale.sessionExpired);
          }
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return LoginPageOne(reloadMsg: myLocale.sessionExpired);
        }

        return logoLoading(myLocale.polls, backButton: true);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildContent() {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3,
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: buildListOp()
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.check_box, color: Colors.white),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf672a7),
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                fixedSize: const Size.fromWidth(200),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              ),
              label: Text(myLocale.vote),
              onPressed: () {
                submitData();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<RadioListTile> buildListOp() {
    List<RadioListTile> opList = [];

    for (var op in widget.opciones!) {
      RadioListTile newItem = RadioListTile(
        title: Text(
          op.opTexto,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
        ),
        value: op.opId,
        groupValue: currentVote,
        activeColor: const Color(0xFFf672a7),
        fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => const Color(0xFFf672a7)),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            currentVote = value;
            // print('Voto $value');
          });
        },
      );

      opList.add(newItem);
    }

    return opList;    
  }

  void submitData() {
    setState(() {
      try {
        _responsePoll = ApiServices().postVoto(widget.encuesta.pollId, currentVote, widget.propiedad);
        dialogContent = responseDialog();
      } on Exception catch (_, e) {
        dialogContent = buildExceptionWidget(e.toString());
      }
    });  
  }

  FutureBuilder<dynamic> responseDialog() {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
      future: _responsePoll,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting && snapshot.hasData) {
          var response = snapshot.data!;
          return Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                elevation: 0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(response['error'] == '1' ? Icons.error : Icons.check, color: response['error'] == '1' ? const Color(0xFFf672a7) : Colors.green),
                      minLeadingWidth: 20,
                      title: Text(
                        '¡${response['status']}!',
                        style: TextStyle(color: response['error'] == '1' ? const Color(0xFFf672a7) : Colors.green, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
                      child: Text(
                        response['msg'],
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.undo, color: Colors.white,),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf672a7),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  fixedSize: const Size.fromWidth(200),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                ),
                label: Text(myLocale.goBack),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (response['error'] == '0') {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EncuestasList(ppUniqid: widget.propiedad),
                        ),
                      );                      
                    } else {
                      dialogContent = buildContent();
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                elevation: 0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Color(0xFFf672a7)),
                      minLeadingWidth: 20,
                      title: Text(
                        myLocale.error,
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFf672a7), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
                      child: Text(
                        myLocale.errorServerCom,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.undo, color: Colors.white,),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf672a7),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  fixedSize: const Size.fromWidth(200),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                ),
                label: Text(myLocale.goBack),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    dialogContent = buildContent();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }

        return const Center(child: SizedBox(height: 30, width: 30, child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xFFf672a7))));
      }
    );
  }

  Widget buildExceptionWidget(String errorMsg) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          elevation: 0,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.error, color: Color(0xFFf672a7)),
                minLeadingWidth: 20,
                title: Text(
                  myLocale.error,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFf672a7), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
                child: Text(
                  errorMsg,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16)
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.undo, color: Colors.white,),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf672a7),
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            fixedSize: const Size.fromWidth(200),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
          ),
          label: Text(myLocale.goBack),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              dialogContent = buildContent();
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```